# Convert Zalgo Text to Plain text

Tags: python, text, python-3.6, zalgo

So I have some zalgo text:

```
Ḩ̡̤̜̩̜̝̉é̪̟̜̗̣̔̊̋̈̅ll̪̟̣̗̣̗̜̜̇̌̋̔̍̉̃̌̏̄̔ọ̘̥̗̇̂̒
```

and I'm trying to turn that into

```
Hello
```

Using python3.6, the function I'm using to convert text to zalgo is

```
def zalgo(text):
    return ''.join([v,v+''.join(choice(list(map(chr,range(768,815))))for i in range(int(normalvariate(10,5))))][v.isalpha()]for v in text)
```

Taken from a code-golf question.

What I'm trying to do is get the string back in python3.6 so the example would return `Hello`

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @AndyK Edited it into the question

Comment: What difficulties are you facing? Have you heard about [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AndyK I'm just looking for a function to turn `Ḩ̡̤̜̩̜̝̉é̪̟̜̗̣̔̊̋̈̅l̠̐̒̆́̎l̪̟̣̗̣̗̜̜̇̌̋̔̍̉̃̌̏̄̔ọ̘̥̗̇̂̒` into `Hello`

Comment: There is no function for that. Note that the also is no function to convert text into Zalgo -- you added it to Python.

Comment: This not a code outsourcing facility. Read the mvce link I've put into the comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may [**`filter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) the alphabets/digits from your string using [**`str.isalnum`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) (or [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) for only alphabets) and [**`join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) it back as:

```
>>> my_str = 'Ḩ̡̤̜̩̜̝̉é̪̟̜̗̣̔̊̋̈̅ll̪̟̣̗̣̗̜̜̇̌̋̔̍̉̃̌̏̄̔ọ̘̥̗̇̂̒'


>>> ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, my_str))
'Hello'
```